# Is there a Dot-Probe Paradigm / visual-probe task available online?

Tags: experimental-psychology, methodology

Is there an online resource to take the [Dot-probe paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-probe_paradigm) test>

When I searched I could only find a guide to set up a server for such a test. However, I don't have the ability to do that.

I'm specifically interested in a test that measures negativity/pessimism bias and tells you the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be an [Inquisit implementation of the dot probe task](http://www.millisecond.com/download/library/DotProbe/) that will run both online and in a lab. Such scripts can presumably be customised to your purposes.

If you want to use this for research purposes, you would need to have access to a licence to Inquisit.

There is also a trial version of the software. You could download the trial of Inquisit and the script and run the script on your computer.